# Ring Structures On $\mathbb {R} ^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

In the book of Musili it is written that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a division ring under usual addition and multiplication for $n=1,2,4$. I have understood this. But after that he said, in those cases we cannot define any other multiplication in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to make it a division ring, i.e., the only multiplication '.' in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the usual multiplication for which $(\mathbb{R}^n,+,.)$ is a division ring (where $n=1,2,4$). The proof is not given in the book. Can anyone help me?

Comment: The statement is not precise; $\mathbb{R}^n$ (with its usual real vector space structure) admits a structure of division *algebra* over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $n\in\{1,2,4\}$.

Comment: @egreg, indeed it is simply wrong. For $n > 1$, the product ring $\mathbb{R}^n$ is never a division algebra.

Comment: @user18921 I guess that “usual multiplication” refers to the vector space structure.

Comment: @egreg, ohh I see. In that case, I doubly agree with your comment; it is *very* poorly worded indeed.

Comment: It's also possible the user thinks "the usual multiplication" is a good description for complex and quaternion multiplication, and didn't anticipate the product ring product.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say that $\Bbb R^n$ is a division algebra under "the usual multiplication," but rather using the multiplications that $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ induce.

The fact that the only finite dimensional associative $\Bbb R$ division algebras are the reals, the complexes, and the quaternions is precisely the [Frobenius theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_%28real_division_algebras%29).

It's too long to prove here, but you can search for a proof under that name.

Comment: The result is true even if we drop the requirement of associativity, but then the proof is remarkably more complicated.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, what about the octonions?

Comment: Yup, the possible dimensions are 1, 2, 4, and 8 (but there are more algebras than the gool ol' four)